# What is the major difference between ` and ' in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am brand new to typescript/javascript/angular, and I am reading some tutorials I keep coming across the following type of thing:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  toString() {
    return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
  }
}
```

Now my question is these are physical back-ticks and everything else I have seen just uses " and ' which I believe are functionally the same so are these two true:

1. `` ` == ' `` ?
2. `` ` === ' ``?

Or is this an Angular/Typescript only thing?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: This is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: ``${sth} `` and multiline strings.

Comment: In short: You can use ` for multi-line strings. But this might not work in older browsers. ' is for normal strings.

Comment: thanks for the link, sorry about the duplicate I could not find that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are enclosed by the back-tick (`` ` ``) character instead of double `"` or single `'` quotes. They can contain placeholders, indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (`${expression}`). The expressions in the placeholders and the text between them get passed to a function. The default function just concatenates the parts into a single string.
>
> - Source: [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

You can use black ticks ` to insert JavaScript notations inside your string. For instance:

```
const name = 'world'

// using ''
let myString1 = 'Hello' + name;

// using ``
let myString2 = `Hello ${name}`
```

`myString1` and `myString2` both have both the same string.

This is a more convenient way of formatting content in JavaScript, no need to concatenate strings, you can insert variables inside strings.

And yes `` ` `` is equal to `'`. Try typing the following in the console:

```
`\`` === '`'
```

It will return as `true`

Comment: so I could also do const name = ` world ` and it would work fine?

Comment: indeed you can. Backticks are "better versions" than single quotes and double quotes.